# Как изменить выражение виртуального столбца по которому секционирована таблица? Ошибка: ORA-54019

Tags: sql, oracle, partition

Есть таблица, которая секционирована по виртуальному столбцу, требуется изменить выражение для этого виртуального столбца, но, по-видимому, это невозможно сделать тем способом, который пробую:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE
MODIFY VIRTUAL_COLUMN 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_DATE(SUBSTR(SOME_COLUMN, 4, 8), 'yyyymmdd'))
```

> ORA-54019: Невозможно изменить выражение виртуального столбца, т.к. этот столбец является столбцом секционирования

Как можно изменить этот виртуальный столбец?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [HHow to solve ORA-54019: Virtual column expression cannot be changed because it is a partitioning column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62534363) от участника [@Dinu Nicolae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7668336/dinu-nicolae)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62534363

Answer (score 2):

Если виртуальный столбец является частью ключа секционирования, то его выражением нельзя изменить.

Если требуется его изменить так, чтобы можно было также изменить схему секционирования, то надо:

- Добавить новый виртуальный столбец с нужным выражением.
- Изменить схему секционирования, чтобы использовать новый виртуальный столбец.

Если версия 18c или выше, то можно сделать с `ALTER TABLE`:

```
create table t (d date, v number as (to_number (to_char (d, 'yyyymmdd' )))) 
    partition by range (v) (
        partition p0 values less than (20200101))
/
alter table t
  modify v number as (to_number (to_char (d, 'yyyymm')))
/
ORA-54019: Невозможно изменить выражение виртуального столбца, 
           т.к. этот столбец является столбцом секционирования
54019. 0000 -  "Virtual column expression cannot be changed because it is a partitioning column"
*Cause:    Attempted to modify the expression of a virtual column that was
           also a partitioning column.
*Action:   This is not supported.

alter table t
  add v2 number as (to_number (to_char (d, 'yyyymm')))
/ 
alter table t
    modify partition by range (v2) (
        partition p0 values less than (202001)
    ) online
/
select column_name 
from user_part_key_columnswhere name = 'T';

COLUMN_NAME
----------------
V2
```

Для более старых версий лучше использовать пакет [DBMS_REDEFINITION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_REDEFINITION.html#GUID-2BA796C4-8B4D-49B4-8A35-4C6F789CD374), чтобы минимизировать время простоя. Например, как показано в [этой статье](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/online-table-redefinition-enhancements-11gr1).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62537012) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>